# ONNXRUNTIME-GPU with multiprocessing and multigpu

Tags: python, multiprocessing, onnxruntime

Suppose that I have 4 Process and 2 GPUs. Running the following code, it works while `n = 1`. If I set `n = 2`, it would be blocked at the second loop.

```py
import onnxruntime as ort
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Onnx:
    def __init__(self, model_path, device_id):
            providers = [('CUDAExecutionProvider', {'device_id': device_id}), 'CPUExecutionProvider']
            options.intra_op_num_threads = 1
            options.inter_op_num_threads = 1
            self.session = ort.InferenceSession(model_path, options, providers=providers)

    def forward(self, **kwargs):
        return self.session.run(None, **kwargs)

def impl(model_path, ctx, num_gpus):
    device_id = ctx % num_gpus
    model = Onnx(model_path, device_id)
    # DO SOMETHING AND FORWARD ONNX MODEL

def main():
    num_workers = 4
    num_gpus = 2
    n = 2
    for i in range(n):
        print("START LOOP {}".format(i))
        cs = [Process(target=impl, args=(model_path, ctx, num_gpus)) for ctx in range(num_workers)]
        [c.start() for c in cs]
        [c.join() for c in cs]
        print("END LOOP {}".format(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Could someone tell me what happened and give some suggestions?

I have tried to init ort session outer subprocess function and pickle it as an arg, following https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/7846#issuecomment-850217402.

Unfortunately, it is also blocked at the second loop.